# distorted output during processing .wav file

Tags: c++, endianness, riff

I want to process a .wav file for example reducing amplitude;
when i use following code the output becomes distorted and that's not pleasant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char* wav_mem;
    ifstream wav_file;
    wav_file.open("1.wav", ios::binary | ios::ate);
    int file_size = wav_file.tellg();
    wav_mem = new char[file_size];
    wav_file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    wav_file.read(wav_mem, file_size);
    int16_t sample = 0;
    wav_file.close();
    for(int i = 44; i <= file_size; i += 2)
    {   
        sample = ((wav_mem[i + 1] << 8) | (wav_mem[i]));
        sample = (int16_t)(sample * 0.5);
        wav_mem[i] = sample;
        wav_mem[i+1] = (sample >> 8);
    }
    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("out.wav", ios::binary);
    out_file.write(wav_mem, file_size);
}
```

How can I fix the distortion?

Comment: Aside: declare and init all in one go: `char* wav_mem = new char[file_size];` after `int file_size = wav_file.tellg();`

Comment: Aside: *don't* use c-style casts use: `sample = static_cast<int16_t>(sample * 0.5);`

Comment: try `uint8_t` for `wav_mem`, or even better, use `int16_t` for the buffer, and re-cast it to `char *` or `void *` for file operations only, avoid your `((wav_mem[i + 1] << 8) | (wav_mem[i]))` math.. with signed char this is IMO wrong way of composing the value back into 16b. (setting all top bits to ones when low 8 bits have sign bit set). (and if `int16_t`, then read only the sample data, not full file, or create proper structure for full file and load that properly) (or recast the sample data pointer at beginning, like `int16_t* sample = reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(wav_mem+44);` or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, i messed up samples when i was trying to convert two bytes to 16 bits, here is the final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream wav_file;
    ofstream out_file;
    wav_file.open("input.wav",ios::binary|ios::ate);
    size_t file_size = wav_file.tellg();
    char * wav_buf = new char[file_size];
    wav_file.seekg (0,ios::beg);
    wav_file.read (wav_buf, file_size);
    wav_file.close();
    int16_t wav_smpl(0);
    char * wav_out = new char[file_size];
    memcpy(wav_out, wav_buf, 44);
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < file_size ; i += 2) 
    {
        memcpy(&wav_smpl , wav_buf + (i + 44) , 2);
        wav_smpl *= 3;
        memcpy(wav_out + (i + 44) , &wav_smpl , 2);
    }
    out_file.open("output.wav",ios::binary);
    out_file.write(wav_out, file_size);
    out_file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your actions on the `.wav` file itself is sound (otherwise I don't know much about it to know if that's the problem) some potential flaws could be:

1. Collecting the output of `tellg` in `int` might cause an overflow. Maybe use `auto` to get the right type ?
2. `wav_mem[i+1] = (sample >> 8);` when `i == file_size` in the loop that might cause an overflow access (beyond the length of `wav_mem`) ?

Edit:
In-fact you can only access `[0, file_size)` indices in a defined manner due to your `wav_mem = new char[file_size];` line. So when `i = file_size` both `wav_mem[i]` and `wav_mem[i+1]` will be UB.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may lie in the use of the bitshift operator `>>` on signed integers. The actual behavior of `<<` according to the standard [has changed in C++14 and is going to change again in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) (*cf*. "Bitwise shift operators"). Either way, it is not a logical bitshift but an arithmetic bitshift.

Instead, I would use `reinterpret_cast` to convert both bytes into one 16-bit integer. I used something like this in the past:

```cpp
int16_t num;
for (size_t i = 0; i < N && wav_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), 2); ++i) {
    audio[i] = double(num);
}

/* do stuff */

for (double x : audio) {
    num = static_cast<int16_t>(x);
    out_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), 2);
}
```

Note that this assumes a LittleEndian architecture, as RIFF uses LittleEndian.

Comment: For a complete example see this repo I set up a couple of years ago for a C++ class I taught: https://gitlab.physik.uni-muenchen.de/J.Greitemann/denoise
It applies a low-pass filter to a noisy piece of audio. Also check out the branch `spectral-subtraction` for more sophisticated noise cancelling.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the mentioned earlier overflow in `tellg` and undefined behaviour in `wav_mem[i + 1]` I think this line is main problem:

```
sample = (int16_t)(sample * 0.5);
```

Behind the scenes the `sample` is converted here to double. Converting back and forth to double and from double may cause minor (but I suppose hearable) rounding errors which I suppose may be the source of distortion. Instead of this use:

```
sample /= 2;
```

Comment: I don't think so. Both of these produce the exact same values of sample. Though, I agree that the latter one is more elegant if that is the _only_ thing that is done.